# Python - Como mostrar ventanas seguidas en un intervalo de tiempo (tkinter, problema mainloop())

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy realizando un programa en python que abre ventanas con imagenes, utilizo Tkinter, sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas. Detallo lo realizado.

1) Cree la funcion1 para generar una ventana y mostrar la imagen1.
2) Cree la funcion2 para generar una ventana y mostrar la imagen2.
3) cree la funcion 3, en la cual llamo a funcion1, coloco un delay (retraso de 3 segundos), luego llamo a la funcion2.

Mi problema es que en el paso 3, solo me muestra la imagen1 debido a que el mainloop culmina mi proceso, entonces ya no se ejecuta el paso 2 ni el paso3.

Este es una draft de mi codigo:

```
    def imagen1(self):
        imagen_1 =Toplevel()
        imagen_1.geometry("900x600")
        lena = "/home/pi/Desktop/imagen_prueb1.jpg"
        def imgShow(img):
            image = Image.open(img)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            w = Canvas(imagen_1)
            w.photo=photo
            w.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = "nw")
            w.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

        imgShow(lena)
        imagen_1.mainloop()

    def imagen2
        imagen_2 =Toplevel()
        imagen_2.geometry("900x600")
        lena = "/home/pi/Desktop/imagen_prueba2.jpg"
        def imgShow(img):
            image = Image.open(img)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            w = Canvas(imagen_2)
            w.photo=photo
            w.create_image(0, 0, image = photo, anchor = "nw")
            w.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

        imgShow(lena)
        imagen_2.mainloop()

    def demo_actividades(self): #Aqui esta el problema, por el mainloop, solo efectua el self imagen1 y ya no efectua ni el delay ni el imagen2

        self.imagen1()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.imagen2()
```

Nota: la idea no es simplemente tener estos 3 pasos, sino gestionar actividades adicionales entre ellos que impliquen tal vez el uso de motores u otros.

Les agradeceria su apoyo.

Comment: mira algun tutorial de multithreading en python

Comment: Estuve revisando el tema de threading pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: revisalo bien , con poner un thread a cada toplevel deberia funcionar

Comment: Justo realice eso exactamente, y a pesar de ello el comportamiento fue el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si entendí bien, pero lo que se me ocurre son dos posibles soluciones. Una de ellas sería cerrar la primer ventana antes de invocar a la segunda, para ello está el comando

```
imagen1.destroy()
```

La segunda sería que intentaras hacerlo con *Threading*, porque efectivamente al tratarse de un loop cada ventana puedes llegar a quedarte estancado en alguno de ellos, como sucede en tu caso. Aquí la cuestión es qué tan compleja quieres que sea tu aplicación.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que la funcion 1 llama a la imagen pero para que se visualice es necesario colocar el mainloop. Pero al hacerlo se sale de la funcion demoactividades. (Nota en el codigo no puse el destroy por que es una version simplicada de mi necesidad, pero si esta considerado)

Comment: Entonces quizá sí te resultaría útil el uso de Threads porque, a como yo lo veo, realmente no sales de la función _demo_actividades_ sino que no se tiene una manera de retornar a la secuencia de ejecución, dado que se queda en el ciclo de la funcion _imagen1_.

       `import threading
        .
        .
        .
        t = threading.Thread(target=imagen1)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=imagen2)
        .
        .
        .
        t.start()
        time.sleep(10)
        t2.start()`

Quizá te funcione. Recuerda declarar las variables correctamente.

Comment: Realice la modificación, sin embargo el resultado es el mismo, solo crea una ventana y si deseo ver la otra ventana debo cerrar la primera a fin que avance a los siguientes pasos.
def demo_actividades():
    
    t1=threading.Thread(target=imagen1())
    t2=threading.Thread(target=imagen2())
    #time.sleep(2)
    #imagen1()
    #imagen2()
    
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    print('funcionas')
    t2.start()

Comment: hay manera de colocar un temporizador en el mainloop, o cerrar el mainloop.

Comment: es (target=imagen1) no (target=imagen1())....

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podrias hacerlo de esta manera en vez de con threads ya que pueden dar problemas

```
import time
from tkinter import *

def imagen1():
        imagen_1 =Toplevel(root)
        imagen_1.geometry("900x600")




def imagen2():
        imagen_2 =Toplevel(root)
        imagen_2.geometry("900x600")




root=Tk()
imagen1()
root.after(3000,imagen2)
root.mainloop()
```

Creas una raiz para asignarla a los toplevels para que no haya problemas despues incias la primera imagen y con la funcion after() es parecido a time.sleep pero lo hace mientras se ejecuta el mainloop a diferencia de time.sleep que lo hace antes , ademas es en milisegundos